# how to run golang project downloaded from github

Tags: go, github

i have downloaded a project from github for some testing. the code is in go language. when i edited the code and run , many errors occoured.
I have tried to run project using D:\go>go run demo command. 
how should i run the project?

here are the errors:

```
D:\go>go run hardentools-master
bin\src\hardentools-master\powershell.go:20:2: cannot find package "errors" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\errors (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\errors (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\gui.go:20:2: cannot find package "flag" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\flag (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\flag (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\adobe.go:20:2: cannot find package "fmt" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\fmt (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\fmt (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\gui.go:26:2: cannot find package "github.com/lxn/walk" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\github.com\lxn\walk (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\github.com\lxn\walk (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\gui.go:27:2: cannot find package "github.com/lxn/walk/declarative" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\github.com\lxn\walk\declarative (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\github.com\lxn\walk\declarative (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\adobe.go:22:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\golang.org\x\sys\windows\registry (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\golang.org\x\sys\windows\registry (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\main.go:73:2: cannot find package "io" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\io (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\io (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\gui.go:22:2: cannot find package "io/ioutil" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\io\ioutil (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\io\ioutil (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\main.go:74:2: cannot find package "log" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\log (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\log (from $GOPATH)
bin\src\hardentools-master\gui.go:23:2: cannot find package "os" in any of:
        D:\go\bin\src\os (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\admin\go\src\os (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell you how to fix your errors if you don't tell us what the errors are, or show us the code.

Comment: @Flimzy i have edited the question. please check

Comment: You Go installation seems to be broken. Install from official source according to official installation instructions and test your installation first.

Comment: @Volker yes, i have installed from official source

Answer (score -1):

You can check the release page, you have an executable ready to use : https://github.com/securitywithoutborders/hardentools/releases

Comment: That's useless if they want to make changes to the code.

Comment: Yes, but the purpose is not defined in the question so it's just in case it's only for testing the app.

Comment: It specifically says "when I edited the code and run, many errors occured".